# Showing validation messages just after binding with Knockout Validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

With  Knockout Validation it appears that validation is performed only when a key is hit on a control which might change an observable value.

When I bind the first time, the validation is not performed (messages are not shown if the initial values are invalid). I just need to focus on one of my input controls and write a letter and unfocus it so that validation is performed.

How can I show all the messages around each control recursively just after the first binding? I tried the `group` solution , but I have a nested hierarchy of `validatedObservable` this produces a maxStackSize exceeded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure knockout.validation to show the messages immediately.

```
ko.validation.init({ messagesOnModified: false });
```

Details about the configuration can be found at the following wiki page:
https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration

Answer (score 0):

You elso can do somthing like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     ko.applyBindings(new vm(), $("#id")[0]);
     $(".validationMessage").css("color", "Red");
     vm.errors.showAllMessages(true);
});
```